# Use label as index marker and use nameref to print the value in the index

Tags: indexing

I have created a name index with the `imakeidx` package. My question is:

**Is it possible to add a `label` as the key for the index and print e.g. `\nameref{label}` in the index?**

The pseudo-code could look like this:

```
\index[nameindex]{some_label}
```

If the label was a label to a persons name, I would like the name to be printed, and not the label itself. Is that possible and how?

Comment: You mean a text label then. One problem may arise: `\nameref` isn't expandable, but as far as I know, `\index` does not try to expand this at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a variation of an older answer by me, writing text labels to the `.aux` file.

The `\labelText` command actually be inside the `\createPerson` command from the other question of the O.P.

I've added an index here to, but only, if the unstarred version is used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\makeindex[name={nameindex},title={Index of persons}]

\newcounter{mylabelcounter}


\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\labelText}{smm}{%
 \IfBooleanF{#1}{%
 \index[nameindex]{#2}% Do not make an index here
 }%
\refstepcounter{mylabelcounter}%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \string\newlabel{#3}{{1}{\thepage}{{#2}}{mylabelcounter.\number\value{mylabelcounter}}{}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\blindtext[5]

\index[nameindex]{\nameref{label:einstein}}
\labelText{Albert Einstein}{label:einstein}

\printindex[nameindex]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just letting people know, what the other question was :) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283230/how-to-make-an-index-of-people-used-in-the-book-with-references-to-page-number

Comment: @FireFly3000: I will add the link to the other question to my answer later on